# What's unique to Saguenay Fjord that doesn't exist in Cape Breton Highlands and Whistler (Highway 99)?

Tags: quebec

Suppose that a tourist already visited  visits to [Cape Breton Highlands National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Breton_Highlands_National_Park), the [Sea-to-Sky Highway 99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia_Highway_99), and Whistler, BC.

Is there anything relevant to them (barring e.g. Québec French), unique to [Saguenay Fjord National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saguenay_Fjord_National_Park), that wouldn't have been already seen?

Comment: I have made some minor edits to your most recent version, in an effort to make the English more natural, and the question more suitable for receiving generic advice rather than needlessly personalised to your family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saguenay's fjords aren't at all like either Cape Breton Highlands or the coast and mountains of southwestern British Columbia.  I wouldn't view any one of them as being at all close to being a substitute for the other:

- Cape Breton is rugged coastal terrain without a lot of inlets.  A highway (the Cabot Trail) runs along the coastline in the park, offering terrific views.
- The B.C. coast between Vancouver and Whistler on BC Highway 99 is rugged and winding.  Tall mountains are on your right as you go northbound, and views of sea inlets are on your left, and you can see fairly rugged islands as well.  Snow covers the taller mountains to your east, even in summer.  This area is special because it's so close to a large city.  Whistler, of course, is home of Whistler-Blackcomb Ski Resort, one of the largest in the continent.
- the Saguenay fjords are different still.  The base terrain is hilly but not super rugged, but it flanks a deep river, the St. Lawrence River, which is one of the most major river systems in North America and is quite wide around Saguenay.  The fjords cut deeply inland and beautifully so.  The surrounding terrain is forest, principally maple, which can be gorgeous in the autumn as its leaves turn orange and red.  The population of this area is the highest; people live throughout this area, whereas the other areas are quite touristy (even though the B.C. highway is close to Vancouver).

Further up the B.C. coast there are deep inlets that are really fjords, but even then, the terrain is different and the feel of the place is different.

One's opinions about scenery are very subjective, and will vary greatly from person to person, but if the Saguenay region looks appealing, I'd say go for it and visit it.  There are also some impressive areas of Quebec further downriver on the St. Lawrence.  Plus, as you mention, the culture of Quebec is very different from anywhere else in Canada.

To really differentiate them, I'd need to know your personal preferences, and we shy away from customizing advice for individuals here, preferring rather to give content that will be of benefit to a broad audience.

Look up information about each area online and see if there is an appeal to visit them.  Frankly, even within very similar-seeming areas, there are significant differences to those who pay attention.  For example, most lump the four Atlantic Canadian provinces together, but I've visited all four and have different opinions about each of them.  The people are different, the scenery is slightly to significantly different, the feel of each place is different.  Some places I appreciate because they are off the beaten track; others I appreciate because they are so gorgeous that the entire world knows.  For example, one of the most popular places to go in Nova Scotia is Peggy's Cove, near Halifax, but I enjoyed our drive down a chain of islands to Westport just as much, and it was bereft of tourists.

Comment: The differences are almost self-evident, but I'll try :)